# Calling WCF service from MVC4 application not returning response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, amazon-web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 application that is calling Amazon Web Services. The amazon service client is implemented in a separate assembly. So architecture is like:
MVC4 -> WCF Client Assembly -> AmazonWebService

This arrangement is working perfectly if i replace MVC4 web application with ASP.Net or a console application. but when I an using MVC4 application, the request is not returning any response. It just looks like response from web service is just the request itself. I am not getting any results from amazon web service.
Is there something i am missing in MVC4 configuration file or some route needs to be added or things like that.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a small issue with xml serializer generated by VS that kept inserting a white space in one of the parameters in soap request. That caused AWS to not send any response values.